# Impulse Response and Frequency Response of a FBLMS filter

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, finite-impulse-response, lms

Suppose I work with sampling frequency `FS` and block length of `L`.
I implemented the Frequency-domain Block LMS (FBLMS) algorithm described [here, slide 16](https://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/ett042/LEC/notes4.pdf), using the *overlap-save* method (to properly convert linear convolution to FFT products). The resulting filter $W$ is a $2L$ complex vector $W \in \mathbb{C}^{2L}$.

1. How do I interpret $W$ as a frequency response? (e.g. take the entire $2L$ coefficient or only the first $L$ coefficients?)
2. How do I convert it to the time-domain representations, i.e. the taps assuming it is a FIR and what is the length ($L$ or $2L$) of its time impulse response?

My hypothesis:

1. $W_f = W[L:2L]$: taking the last L+1 coefficients
2. $w_{\mathrm{taps}} = \mathrm{Re}(\mathcal{F}^{-1}(W))$ taking the real part of the inverse DFT

To justify 1 I used the FBLMS algorithm/code:

```
# Estimate of desired from reference after current filter
y = np.real(np.fft.ifft(w_lms * fft_u))
desired_estimate = y[L:]
```

where `fft_u = FFT([u(prev_block), u(current_block)])`. Since we discard the first $L-1$ samples, I assume that the $L-1$ first coefficients of `w_lms` are redundant or irrelevant.

For 2, if 1 is correct then

```
w_taps = np.fft.rfft(W_f) # 2*L real coefficients
```

Comment: Did you try to just feed a Kronecker delta function as the input signal of your filter? That's the impulse response in the time domain.

Comment: I suspect that inserting a delta is a too degenerate case, in which I will have many 0's but I won't know which of them are redundant.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that what you call $L$ here corresponds to $M$ in the cited reference? If that's the case, 1. $\mathbf{W}$ (with length $2L$) is the frequency response that is applied to the input block of length $2L$. It may have symmetries due to the fact that the input signal is real, but the frequency response is the entire $\mathbf{W}$. 2. I don't understand why you are taking the real part of the inverse DFT. Could you explain? If I'm correct, simply $\mathbf{w} = \text{IDFT}\left\{\mathbf{W}\right\}$.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, $L=M$ of slide 16. Can you also expand and explain your answer? I know that if $W_f$ has a conjugate mirror symmetry, than the inverse DFT should be real, but in real code you have to enforce ```real``` to kill imaginary part (even if it is ```0j``` or ```1e-16j```).

Comment: I understand the numerical accuracy reasons to only use the real part of the IDFT. Regarding the impulse response $\mathbf{w}$ of the filter: The length of the (time-domain) impulse response is $2L$. Taking only half of the output samples to calculate the output signal is part of the overlap-save algorithm, not part of the filter itself. Maybe it helps if you specify your goal: What do you want to do with the filter's impulse response?

Comment: I want to do with the filter two things: I generate a FIR $h$ (and its frequency response ```H = fft(h)``` which serve as my ground-truth. Then I try to estimate it by the FLMS filter $w$. (that is: ```desired = lfilter(h, 1, reference)```). After I estimate $W$ I want to obtain its time impulse response $w_{taps}$ to filter the reference (in the time-domain) by the ```scipy.signal.lfilter``` function: ```y = lfilter(w_taps, 1, reference)```.